# How to Disable Drag n Drop on Samsung (not Google) Calendar

Tags: samsung, calendar

Too many times I am trying to add a new event on Samsung Calendar, and somehow I select onto an existing event and suddenly this previous event enters into drag mode.  If I do not recall where the event was, I am lost because there is no way to cancel this drag mode, the previous event will end up wherever I release my finger to drop it and there is no way that I can tell to undo the moving of the event.

How do I turn off drag and drop capability on Samsung Calendar?  Or, is there a way to undo these accidental moves of existing events?

Comment: If you don't find a way to disable or cancel the drag&drop you could switch to a different calendar app (Google or whatever). Calendars apps on Android are usually just fron-end apps to the Android calendar back-end. So you all apps show the same data.